# OSMxn - How to plot to a specific position and resolution using a bounding box and figsize

Tags: geopandas, osmnx

I have code using OSMNX (great tool, thank you GB!) that is attempting to convert OSMNX output to a raster file (a png image) with a specific resolution and bounding box because it needs to align with an existing raster.  I am using ox.projection.project_graph() to convert to the necessary crs (UTM 33N) and ox.plot_graph() to try to plot using the required bounding box and figsize to get the desired image resolution -> raster cell size.  I must be missing something because I consistently get an error (ValueError: Image size of 277704x419976 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction) even though I specified a small figsize (3857 x 5833).  The bounding box is in meters as is the projected_to crs.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's that section of the code:

```
...
# Fairly standard up to this point.  G is a valid MultiDiGraph and the other variables all have appropriate values.

# This works great: 
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, node_color=nc, node_size=ns, node_zorder=2, edge_color=ec, edge_linewidth=ew)

# So does this:
pG = ox.projection.project_graph(G, to_crs={'init':'epsg:32633'})
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(pG, node_color=nc, node_size=ns, node_zorder=2, edge_color=ec, edge_linewidth=ew)

# But this gives an error: (ValueError: Image size of 277704x419976 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction) 
# even though figsize is only 3857x5833.
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(pG, bbox=(6686683.721299999, 6511693.721299999, 743864.5602, 628154.5602), figsize=(3857, 5833), dpi=30, node_color=nc, node_size=ns, node_zorder=2, edge_color=ec, edge_linewidth=ew)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `figsize` argument is just passed along to matplotlib, where it is expected to be [in inches](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure).

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, CA, USA', network_type='drive')
Gp = ox.project_graph(G)
nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(Gp, edges=False)
c = nodes.unary_union.centroid
bbox = c.y + 500, c.y - 500, c.x - 500, c.x + 500
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(Gp, bbox=bbox, figsize=(5, 5))
```

Comment: GBoeing, thanks so much for responding yourself.  It's all working now.  I've included my updated code below.  Best, John

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to GBoeing for his answer and his great work on OSMnx.  After trying to come up with a standardized process for creating rasters with prescribed bounds and cell size (resolution), I came full-circle and realized that all that really needs to happen is to cancel out the dpi by dividing by 100.  In other words, use figsize=(58.33, 38.57) to get a 5833x3857 image.  Here's all I did:

```
...
# (pG is a valid projected MultiDiGraph and the other variables all have appropriate values)
# To create an image that's 5833x3857 using the 100dpi default, 
# just divide the desired dimensions by 100 and use that for figsize.

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(pG, figsize=(58.33, 38.57), bbox=(6686683.721299999, 6511693.721299999, 743864.5602, 628154.5602), dpi=100, node_color=nc, node_size=ns, node_zorder=2, edge_color=ec, edge_linewidth=ew)

fig.savefig("C:/output_path/output_file.png", dpi=100, pad_inches=0.0)

# This yields an image with the desired bounds, dimensions, and therefore cell size (resolution).
```